# Issue with migrate on server

Tags: django, postgresql

I have deployed my django project to a digital ocean server and sucessfully installed all requirements. However, when I run migrate, after makemigrations, I get the following exception:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_permission" already exists

Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: formtools, django_filters, djcelery, storages
  Apply all migrations: sessions, admin, sites, auth, contenttypes, directory, easy_thumbnails
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Creating table celery_taskmeta
    Creating table celery_tasksetmeta
    Creating table djcelery_intervalschedule
    Creating table djcelery_crontabschedule
    Creating table djcelery_periodictasks
    Creating table djcelery_periodictask
    Creating table djcelery_workerstate
    Creating table djcelery_taskstate
  Installing custom SQL...
  Installing indexes...
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying auth.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 161, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 68, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 102, in apply_migration
    migration.apply(project_state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 108, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, project_state, new_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 36, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 262, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 103, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_permission" already exists
```

How can I fix this  - please help!

Comment: Is this the first time you apply migrations?

Comment: Yes, there are no migration files as yet. It's a fresh install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to delete the db on the server, recreate it and rerun initial migrations. After investigation I discovered the issue was a result of a mismatch between the db structure on the server and the migration files pushed from local. There can be several causes for this to happen including conflicting structural changes in a single or subsequent migration file. This is rare but can happen.

**Never push migration files to your server and always run makemigrations on the server**. Add migration files to your git ignore list so that the local and server migration files stay apart.

Comment: Not pushing migrations to the servers means they are absent in the files. So when you makemigrations on the server then go back to the local machine, add a field for example, push it to the server, (remember no migrations files on the server after a push), makemigrations on the server you run in a rabbit hole of problems: makemigrations can't see the new field because there are no previous migration files to compare to! It tries to create the model again, but it won't be created because it's already in the tables. You end up in a deadlock. Less than ideal behavior.

Comment: @krafter I have updated my answer to clarify that the migration files should be added to git ignore so the local and server ones stay apart. Remember when you run makemigrations the migration files are created - be it local or on server so the issue you describe of no migration files being present does not exist.

Comment: Sorry, I just need to vent my frustration and desperation with this issue. For about 3 days I've been trying to save my DB and fix the stupid migrations.
For me git-ignoring the migration folder means that my DigitalOcean App doesn't have migration files on the server. Indeed, they are created after running makemigrations, but later after the next git push they get deleted.
At this point I'm questioning my career choices and in a complete desperation.

Comment: And I tried EVERYTHING. 
At this point I deleted all the data using _flush_ method, but the DB still remains corrupted. 
_inspectdb_ output matches with my models perfectly after my manual fix.
All this happened just from using _makemigrations_ and _migrate_ commands, nothing else. 
Add a field, delete migrations, delete a field, mess up the order of operations and voila - you end up in a very bad situation. You are lucky if you can fix it manually.
**This should not happen**, or at least must be fixable with standard commands, not by diving under the hood.

Comment: @krafter Don't despair - I also spent days trying to fix this issue. The entry in my gitignore file is `api/migrations/` where api is the name of the app. Flushing your db would only have cleared that data, not the db structure which is why you are still having issues. In this case, as you have already cleared the data, the best course of action is to delete the db entirely and create a new one and then run your initial migrations on that. Just make sure there are no migration files from your local instance on the server before doing so.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be running makemigrations on the server. You do that locally, on your development machine, and commit them to source control. Then you run the actual migrate command when you deploy.

For now, you'll probably need to drop and recreate your database on the server, then re-run migrate.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your migrations and database desynchronized.

Try recreating your database and then running `./manage.py migrate`.

Also, you shouldn't run `./manage.py makemigrations` on server. Take a look at [workflow](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#workflow).

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't need to upgrade Django manually - the Django will be upgraded automatically along with other dependencies when you update tendenci with

```
pip install -r requirements/tendenci.txt --upgrade
```

or just

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade
```

Please uninstall Django and djcelery then run the above command. You might need to fake djcelery 0001.

```
python manage.py migrate djcelery 0001 --fake
```

Please note that tendenci is currently compatible to Django 1.8.x.